# How to get Authorize.net response in WooCommerce Authorize.net AIM Gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I'm using [WooCommerce Authorize.net AIM Gateway](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/authorize-net-aim/) in WP 4.0.1

it doesn’t tell specifically what the error is.  Instead it gives you a generic **“An error occurred…”** error and the user doesn’t know for sure what is wrong and what to re-enter.

OR

**An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment**
But not telling the actual cause of error.

We have contacted WooCommerce and the vendor SkyVerge and asked about this.  SkyVerge said they are working on a new version that does a better job with this.  But, those changes are at least a month away.

So I want to grab the response code that Authorize.net returns and show the proper message to end users.

Like [here](http://developer.authorize.net/tools/responsereasoncode/) Authorize.net is returning.

Comment: Same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ezOSC this link page is not found